# Is there an MVC /EF best practice design for UI workflow for CRUD of a new object with a simple 2 table master/detail database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The scaffolding in Visual studio 2012 with MVC 4 and EF 5 provides for entry of individual records from separate controllers, but each edit and insert of related tables are separate.

What is the best practice in MVC for a single page that allows a user to enter both master and detail on the same form.  Do I have to manipulate objects in the controller or is there some way that EF can handle it for me?

Seems like a very basic requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to roll this, the easiest is probably just using ajax requests and partial views to load the child records.

Flow is basically create your master. Save it. Once saved, enabled entry of child records. When saved they simply are ajax post requests back to an MVC controller that saves the data and returns the most up to date JSON data. The javascript code that triggered your ajax call then in turn binds that new data to a list - either by manually creating the entry or using something like knockout.js

Read only display:
http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/master-details-knockout-aspnet-mvc.html

CRUD operations:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Detail-CRUD-Operations-fbe935ef